# Set value to a certain color in Matlab colorbar

Tags: image, matlab, vector, pixel, colorbar

In Matlab consider a **MxN** matrix **A** with values in **[-o p]** with M,N as integer values and o,p as double values. The number of values on either side of origo in **M** and **N** are not necessarily even.

**A** is visualised using Matlabs **imagesc** and **colorbar**.

How can I force colorbar to set values from **A** that are close to zero as a certain color?

Please note that I do not wish to (for example) 'hard code' zero (0) as green (0 128 0), but instead I wish to use the default rgb or hsv colormap and have it adjust to the values in **A** whilst still keeping zero (or close to zero) in green color tone.

Comment: Adjust the [color limits](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html?refresh=true) which control the mapping of the colorbar to your data

Comment: I attempted this but was not able to map near-zero or zero values to a specific region of the gradient. How would you go about mapping say [-71 ... 0 ... 300] so that zero and values close to it are in the green section of the gradient?

Comment: Apart from creating a custom colormap, you would need to do `caxis([-300 300])`

Comment: Well, I posted a suggestion below but I feel as if it is extremely inefficient. There has to be a faster way to do such a trivial task I imagine. For example if the negative values in A are just slightly below zero and the positive values are in the 1000's or greater having to do a [-1000 1000] seem not efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the 0 value to actually be in the middle of your colormap, you will want to set your color limits (using [`caxis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html?refresh=true) of the [`CLims`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#prop_CLim) property of the axes) after determining the maximum magnitude of your data:

```
limit = max(abs(data(:)));
caxis([-limit, limit]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am going with. I really feel that there is a faster/better way of doing this so please post improvements.

```
[minM minMlix] = min(oM(:));
[maxM maxMlix] = max(oM(:));
gr1 = abs( minM );
gr2 = abs (maxM );
if ( gr1 > gr2 )
    maxM = gr1;
elseif (gr1 < gr2 )
    minM = -maxM;
end
caxis([minM maxM])
```

Comment: What about `val = max(abs(oM(:))); caxis([-val, val]);`

Comment: Yes indeed. Post it as a solution if you want me to up vote it.